# How to dynamically send data from client-side to a database?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I am trying to build a website that allows users to make sketches. Along with the sketches, the users pass in values like `targetX`, `targetY`, `sizeX` and `sizeY` that specify the final sketch's dimensions and target vertices. After the user draws an element and clicks on save, that element is added to another canvas on the right which contains all the elements that the user has drawn so far. This canvas also lets the user resize and drag the elements to wherever the user desires them to be in the sketch. I am using Flask to host the website and PostgreSQL to store the elements and the aforementioned values.

The webpage looks something like this:
[image]

What I want to do is, for the current sketch canvas, as the user drags and resizes the elements I want to update those values in the database along with that.

The PostgreSQL database looks something like the following (data column is truncated to fit here):
[image]

What I tried to do is the following:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:database1@localhost:5432/sketch2photo";
client = new pg.Client(conString);
```

and then later in the code I tried to update the values as:

```
function handleMouseOut(e){
    selver = -1
    selimg = -1
    draggingImage = false 

    var client = new Client(conString);
    client.connect();

    images.forEach((img, i) => {
        //update the target values in the database
        client.query("UPDATE files SET targetx = $1, targety = $2, sizex = $3, sizey = $4 WHERE target_id = $5", [img.ul.x, img.ul.y, img.ur.x - img.ul.x, img.ll.y - img.ul.y, i], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            } else {
                console.log("target updated");
            }
        });

    })
    client.end();
}
```

But this doesn't work and says `pg is not defined` and also messes up other functions of the canvas. I tried to search more about it and I found that we cannot connect to the database from the client side as it may cause a security concern. How do I proceed to do this?

I am very new to JavaScript and web development so any input will be really helpful.

Comment: Use an [application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server).

Comment: I am already using Flask for storing the sketches. I want to update the values using the client side javascript code.

Comment: I have edited the post and added information about the server. Please have a look.

Comment: As a developer you should be able to search for documentation and tutorials, e.g. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/database/ or https://stackabuse.com/using-sqlalchemy-with-flask-and-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

You should not be connecting to a database client-side, i.e from the browser. If you look at compatibility for `pg`, it's for `nodejs`

The major reason you should not connect from the browser is that you would be exposing any Auth credentials.  As mentioned in comments, you should connect to the database via an application server, e.g. `express` and have your client in the browser call an API endpoint on your server

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do get some idea now. It would really be helpful if you could point to an example so that I can understand it better. Sorry for the trouble, I am extremely new to javascript and web development.

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/nodejs-expressjs-postgresql-crud-rest-api-example/ is a starting point for the backend, you'll need to send your data to the backend via HTTP, something like this https://www.google.com/amp/s/attacomsian.com/blog/axios-javascript%3famp

Comment: I do have a flask backend for the webpage, do I need to use express.js then? Your second link isn't opening